# PHP Warning: require_once(/apps/backend/config/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, symfony

I have downloading site and its appeared error please help me to fix the issue.

I have find out similar question but its not actually related to me and may be  i cant find out, please help me solve the issue

```
Warning: require_once(/apps/backend/config/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/starpass/codmall.in/mm-admin100/index.php on line 12


Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/apps/backend/config/config.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/starpass/codmall.in/mm-admin100/index.php on line 12
```

Config File

```
    <?php

// include project configuration
include(SF_ROOT_DIR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php');

// symfony bootstraping
require_once($sf_symfony_lib_dir.'/util/sfCore.class.php');
sfCore::bootstrap($sf_symfony_lib_dir, $sf_symfony_data_dir);

$sf_root_dir = sfConfig::get('sf_root_dir');
sfConfig::add(array(
  'sf_web_dir_name' => '../',
  'sf_web_dir'      => $sf_root_dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'../',
  'sf_upload_dir_name' => 'siteuploads',
  'sf_upload_dir'   => $sf_root_dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'../'.'siteuploads',
));
```

Index.php

```
    <?php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] !='codmall.in') {
    header('Location: https://codmall.in'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],TRUE,301);
    exit;
}

define('SF_ROOT_DIR',    realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../codsmal'));
define('SF_APP', 'backend');
define('SF_ENVIRONMENT','codmall');
define('SF_DEBUG', true);

require_once(SF_ROOT_DIR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'apps'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.SF_APP.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php');

sfContext::getInstance()->getController()->dispatch();
```

Comment: this looks very odd ... which symfony version is this supposed to be?

Comment: Are sure the prefixed slash of the path is correct?

Comment: @Jakumi Symfony Version 1.0.20

Comment: @MarkusZeller Sir I have not place my script folder on Public_html its on Root Directory So Can you mentioned which slash you are saying about.

Comment: The directory `codsmal` seem to be missing wherever is supposed to be, making the `define('SF_ROOT_DIR')` evaluate to `false`.

Comment: If the file in question can not be included, have you checked whether it exists under the given path? If it does not exist, you should adjust the path. Additionally, you should check for updates - Symfony 1.0.20 is more than ten years old, and you might run into a lot of problems when running it today